# PhoneGap/Cordova pushplugin iOs register callback not firing

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working on my first PhoneGap/Cordova application and am having problems getting the iOS push notification working.

My environment is as follows:

- Cordova version: 3.5.0-0.2.7
- Push Plugin Version: 2.4.0
- XCode version: 6.1.1

and here is the code

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.register(mag.notifications.tokenHandler, mag.notifications.errorHandler, { "badge": "true", "sound": "true", "alert": "true", "ecb": "mag.notifications.onNotificationAPN" });

tokenHandler: function (result) {
    mag.environment.alert("iOS registration successful.");
    mag.notifications.registerId(result);
},

errorHandler: function (error) {
    mag.environment.alert(error);
    console.log(error);
},

onNotificationAPN: function (e) {
    debugger;
    mag.environment.alert("iOS notification received");
},
```

However no matter how I try to test or deploy (iOS simulator, on device through xCode, on device through test flight) none of the callbacks are ever fired and no errors appear.

in the apple dev centre I have my app ID set up and push notifications are enabled for both development and distribution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,I had had not joy in configuring this so I thought "There must be a better way".

I came across this service https://www.pushwoosh.com/

and it integrated an worked straight away - yeah.

So I guess this will be the solution going forward.  Right now their free service is good enough for me and should my needs outgrow I think the paid services are reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it turned out that I had the "Badge App Icon" turned off for my app in the iOS notification settings. Turning that on fixed the problem.

**UPDATE:**

Now I can even turn "Badge App Icon" back off and the callback is still firing correctly. Even after reinstalling the app.